# How to fix proxy issue with npm and '@' in password?

Tags: angular, cmd

I am trying to run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.13` However, I realized that because I am blocked by a proxy I have to add that setting. The issue I am having is that I have a `@` in my password. Since this is the case, when it renders in the `npm config list` it shows `%407` instead of the `@` sign. Please nay help would be appreciated.

I have tried using `^` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.13
```

Comment: It still doesn't fix the proxy issue. I still get the same ```%40``` instead of the ```@```